# discord js asynchronous object

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to built a bot where you type a command and it starts a little mini game. I want it to be able to instantiate multiple game objects so that multiple people can play at the same time, each with their own game. The problem is that I don't know how to create an asynchronous object, with event driven functions, like a "branch" of the main client. Is it possible to do that, or I would have to update each game instance in the main script methods?

Comment: I'm a little bit lost but... there are no such things as "asynchronous objects". What I would do in your case is just using websockets and update the corresponding state data based on the client interaction with the server.

You would probably have a "games" object, so... a message comes from the client, the server process it, and updates the game state, finally sends the response to the client, client updates anything it needs to be updated... and repeat until exit.

A good thing to have in mind is that Node may fall short for CPU-heavy tasks.

Comment: By the way, I may be misunderstanding your question. I found it really confusing honestly.

Answer (score 0):

There are no things as "asynchronous objects" in JS: You can either write a custom class and use a websocket or use a database and a loop (Which is what I use for example, as I find it easier to realize. You basically change each state of your game object after each round to your database. If you don't understand what I mean, I can send you an example from my bot

Comment: If you could send me an example, please do. I'm trying to do something like in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fWdU8JCT6Y). Go to the video section "simultaneous games". I would like to know how does he updates each game object.

Comment: @Galarmo in [this](https://github.com/JonathanTheZero/Utopia/tree/master/src/commands/wars) directory, you can see how I did it for my bot. Basically save the state of the game as a JSON object and save it after every move. This also has the advantage that the users can come back later to continue